# Android txtView1.getText().Equals(R.strings.valueOfTextView) always evaluate to false

Tags: android, equals, gettext

not sure what I'm doing wrong but I try to compare a string like

```
boolean state = ((TextView) v).getText().toString().trim().equals(R.string.[some-value]);
```

This always evaluate to false, but when I debug, the output value of (TextView v).getText() is the correct value I want to compare. I also tried

```
boolean state = ((TextView) v).getText().equals(R.string.[some-value]);
```

As said, when I debug I can see that the value returned by getText() matches the value I defined in the strings.xml for [some-value].

I can work around this issue by comparing the Id of the TextView clicked. But I want to know why the above equals doesn't work. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To read [string from resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) use `mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.[some-value])`

---

So you code should be

```
boolean state = ((TextView) v).getText().toString().trim().equals(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.[some-value]));
```

Answer (score 1):

`R.string.[some-value]`  is an integer value.

you should get first String resource as

```
((TextView) v).getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(context.getString(R.string.[some-value]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `getString()` for your string resources.

```
((TextView) v).getText().toString().trim().equals(getString(R.string.[some-value]))
```

Comment: In fragment `getActivity().getString(R.string.[some-value])`

Answer (score 1):

**@Stephan**

### What is your fault

You are missing  `getString()`

```
boolean state = ((TextView) v).getText().toString().equals(getString(R.string.[Your_Sting]));
```

**public final String getString (int resId, Object... formatArgs)**

> Returns a localized formatted string from the application's package's
>   default string table, substituting the format arguments as defined in
>   Formatter and format(String, Object...)

Try this way .I hope it will works

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
boolean state = ((TextView) v).getText().equals(getString(R.string.[some-value]));
```